# Number of ways to tile a room with $I$-Shaped and $L$-Shaped Tiles

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle, tiling

There is a room of dimensions $2\times n$. You have to tile it using $2$ types of tiles:

- I-Shaped Tile ($2\times1$)
- L-Shaped Tile ($2\times1 + 1$)

[image]

However, you are forbidden to use any tiling where any four corners of the tiles meet.

For example for a $2\times4$ room, the first three will be counted and the last one will not be counted.

[image: Example]

**My Attempt**

If the condition that four corners cannot meet wasn't given, a pretty neat recurrence can be formed.

$$f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2) + 2g(n-1)$$
$$g(n) = f(n-2) + g(n-1)$$

with $g(0) = g(1) = 0$ and $f(0) = f(1) = 1$ where $f(n) = $ number of ways of tiling a $2\times n$ rectangle and $g(n)=$ number of ways of tiling  a $2\times n$ rectangle with a square missing on top.

Hence, we multiply $g(n-1)$ by $2$ when calculating $f(n)$ because the missing square can be at the top or the bottom.

I am unable to find such a recurrence with the extra given condition.

Comment: Doron Zeilberger's student Paul Raff implies in [his dissertation](https://rucore.libraries.rutgers.edu/rutgers-lib/26384/PDF/1/play/) that this indeed has a linear recurrence.

Comment: Can someone confirm the first few values? I get $1,2,5,10,22,49,105 \dots$

Comment: @MichaelBiro that matches what I get.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variant can be settled by splitting up into three cases:

- $f_1(n)$, the number of ways to tile a rectangle ending with a flat line,
- $f_2(n)$, the number of ways to tile a rectangle where two corners meet in the middle,
- $g(n)$, the number of ways to tile a rectangle where the top right square is missing.

We have
$$
   f_1(n) = f_1(n-1) + f_2(n-1) + 2 g(n-1)
$$ 
because the last tile of a rectangle ending in a flat line can either be an I tile or an L tile oriented in two ways. We just have
$$
   f_2(n) = f_1(n-2)
$$
since the only way to create an $f_2$-type rectangle is to put down two horizontal dominoes at the end, and just as before, we have
$$
   g(n) = f_1(n-2) + f_2(n-2) + g(n-1).
$$

---

From here, it's also possible to write down a linear recurrence for just the total $f(n) = f_1(n) + f_2(n)$ in terms of $f(n-1), f(n-2), \dots$. We have $f(n) = f_1(n) + f_2(n) = f_1(n) + f_1(n-2)$, so it's enough to solve for $f_1(n)$. In fact, as a linear combination of $f_1$ and its translate, $f$ will satisfy the same recurrence relation as $f_1$ with different initial conditions.

From $g(n) = f_1(n-2) + f_1(n-4) + g(n-1)$, we get the infinite series $g(n) = f_1(n-2) + f_1(n-3) + 2f_1(n-4) + 2f_1(n-5) + \dotsb$, and this gives us a recurrence
\begin{align}
f_1(n) &= f_1(n-1) + f_2(n-1) + 2g(n-1) \\
  &= f_1(n-1) + f_1(n-3) + 2g(n-1) \\
  &= f_1(n-1) + 3f_1(n-3) + 2f_1(n-4) + 4f_1(n-5) + 4f_1(n-6) + \dotsb \\
\end{align}
Subtracting $f_1(n-1)$ from $f_1(n)$, we get
$$
   f_1(n) - f_1(n-1) = \color{red}{(f_1(n-1) + 3f_1(n-3) + 2f_1(n-4) + 4f_1(n-5) + 4f_1(n-6) + \dotsb )} - \color{blue}{(f_1(n-2) + 3f_1(n-4) + 2f_1(n-5) + 4f_1(n-6) + 4f_1(n-7) + \dotsb )}
$$
and most of the red terms cancel with blue terms, leaving us with
$$
   f_1(n) - f_1(n-1) = f_1(n-1) - f_1(n-2) + 3f_1(n-3) - f_1(n-4) + 2f_1(n-5) 
$$
or $f_1(n) = 2f_1(n-1) - f_1(n-2) + 3f_1(n-3) - f_1(n-4) + 2f_1(n-5)$. As observed earlier, this also means that the recurrence $$f(n) = 2f(n-1) - f(n-2) + 3f(n-3) - f(n-4) + 2f(n-5)$$ holds.

---

The first few nonzero terms of the sequence are $1, 1, 2, 5, 10, 22, 49, 105, 227, 494, 1071, \dots$, as computed by @PeterKagey in the comments and in the upcoming [OEIS listing](https://oeis.org/A329185).

Comment: I submitted this sequence as a [draft](https://oeis.org/draft/A329185) to the OEIS. Once approved, it will be [here](https://oeis.org/A329185).

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the initial conditions for this recurrence are $f(0) = f(1) = 1, f(2) = 2, f(3) = 5$, and $f(4) = 10$. The sequence begins 
$1, 1, 2, 5, 10, 22, 49, 105, 227, 494, 1071, 2322, 5038, 10927, 23699, 51405, \dots$

Comment: I have some general questions on what happens after you find $k$ "inter-related" recurrences, like the $k=3$ here inter-relating $f_1, f_2, g$. (1) Is it always possible to turn the system into $k$ separate recurrences? I.e. write $f_1(n)$ only in terms of a finite number of $f_1(n-t)$ and no $f_2$ etc. (2) Is it always possible to write a recurrence on $f(n)$ using only a finite number of $f(n-t)$, where $f$ is the sum (or any linear combo?) of the $f_i$?  I know the matrix way of writing the $k$ interrelated recurrences, but I can't quite see how to "decouple" and then "sum" ...

Comment: @antkam It's always possible just by the general argument of "a system of $k$ linear recurrences leads to $k$ rational generating functions, which have their own decoupled linear recurrences", but I'm not sure that I have a general method to point to.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand enough about generating functions to understand your argument. :) Anyway, are you saying there is not a method like take inter-related recurrences in matrix form, then row-reduce it or diagonalize it etc and it will always work? So what happened here, when you found the finite recurrences for $f_1$ and $f$, that was art instead of procedural? Also, even if you can decouple the $k$ recurrences, does that also imply you can write a recurrence on the sum $f$? Here you relied on $f$ being a lin comb of $f_1$ and its translates, but that doesn't always happen, right?

Comment: @antkam I'm sure that there is a method, but what I did in the answer was just tricks that don't always work. One general way to do it would be to solve for the closed form of $f_1, f_2, g$ (in terms of exponential functions), from there get the closed form for $f(n) = f_1(n) + f_2(n)$, and finally come up with a recurrence given the closed form (which is sort of the reverse of the general procedure for solving a linear recurrence).

Comment: I upvoted already when I first saw your answer, but now I wish I could upvote again for this little discussion.  :)  Thanks!